# return largest number in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, arr[i]);
      return largest;
    }
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

I need to return the largest number from each erray. When I run my code with console.log, it prints out the largest number of each array but when i return it, only the largest number from array 0 returns. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return` exits the function, you need to create an array and add the largest values to it.

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result.push(Math.max.apply(Math, arr[i]));
  }
  return result;
}

document.body.innerHTML = largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `map` instead of `for`

```js
function largestOfFour(arrs) {
  return arrs.map(function(arr){
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
  });
}

document.body.innerHTML = largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `Array.prototype.reduce()`

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(p, c, index, arr){
      p.push(Math.max.apply(null, c));
      return p;
    }, []);
}
```